# Are Furia Ninja and Anime Ninja the same game?

Tags: unlimited-ninja

Are [Furia Ninja](http://www.soargames.com/) and Anime Ninja the same game? I couldn't tell the difference between them.

[image: Furia Ninja]

Comment: @downvoters, could you explain why? I can't find anything in the FAQ that says anything about this kind of question. It's perfectly answerable by someone who has played both games and OP even provided a picture, the only thing it lacks is some research...

Comment: @Kevin you just gave the reason why the downvotes probably happened(lack of research). As an extra note: calling out to downvotes tends to attract more of them.

Comment: @Arperum I've seen lots of question which were really just a google search away from being answered that still received a lot of upvotes. I'm also not too sure about "calling out downvoters attracts more of them" nor do I really care, I was just wondering about their reasons, not trying to "call them out".

Comment: @Kevin, you interpret that this is a good question. Why would you not care if this gets down voted and deleted, as a result? The calling out down voters is, unfortunately, accurate. It is a misuse of the system, but it happens.

Comment: There may be a lot of other similar questions with upvotes, but this one is beind downvoted because [Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught). (Seriously tough, downvotes aren't close votes. They don't need reasons. If the question irks you enought to sacrifice a rep point to downvote it, any user is free to do so.)

Comment: @DJPirtu - It is free to downvote on questions.

Comment: @DJ Pirtu, negative scores also push questions into the low quality queue. So they don't automatically cause closure, but if they outweight upvotes, they can lead to it.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the two games, side by side, I believe it is fairly obvious that they are the same game. The game is Unlimited Ninja. "Anime Ninja" is a name used by an English server, while "Furia Ninja" is a name used by a Spanish server.

[image]

> **To quote [the Unlimited Ninja Wiki](http://unlimitedninja.wikia.com/wiki/) page on [Game Hosts](http://unlimitedninja.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Hosts):**
>   Hosts of the game can be very different.
>   The name and some parts of the game can be different on every host.
>   ...
>   - AN - [Anime Ninja](http://ninja.playwebgame.com/) - English host
>   ...
>   - FN - [Furia Ninja](http://www.soargames.com/) - Spanish Host SoarGames

---

In other words, the core game is the same. However, being an MMO that is hosted by many different servers, each server would have its own different take on things. These differences may include censorship, game mechanic changes or other elements that create a different experience.